# How to export data (entire database) from a meteor deployed app to another meteor app with a diffrent address?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I deployed a meteor app with like address xxx.meteor.com; now, I want to export all the database of this app to another meteor app with a different address www.xxxx.com.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) commands to do this.

A tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/)

Comment: `meteor mongo --url xxxx.meteor.com` command gives you mongo database URL. So you can dump your database via `mongodump` with this URL.

Comment: @delgermurun:  I do it but does not work for me; "couldn't connect to [roduction-db-d1.meteor.io:27017] couldn't connect to server roduction-db-d1.meteor.io:27017
" ; have you an example with mongodump??

Comment: First of all given url from `meteor mongo` valid for one minute. So make sure your url is valid.

Secondly given url's format is `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>`. You take that pieces and pass them to `mongodump` separately. `mongodump --host <host> --port <port> --username <username> --password <password> --db <db_name>